# How to calculate a sample size for a longitudinal study with repeated data?

Tags: mixed-model, sample-size, statistical-power, nested-data

Did you know a program or logiciel that allows to calculate the sample size for a longitudinal study with repeated data ?

And if my subjects are nested in some schools, how I calculate the sample size ? Does that change anythig ?

Thanks for your answers,

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3734029/ & https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12306 (easier read) are good places to start; both papers are open.

Comment: Simulation !!!!

Comment: Yes but how ? With which software ?